# Spring Cloud Contracts - No consumer set up for topic [...]

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-contract

I am currently developing API compatibility check using Spring Cloud Contracts. I set up everything like documentation says. But I encountered a problem - `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No consumer set up for topic [testSyncTopic]`. That exception is thrown in `KafkaStubMessages` class. So I assumed that this is library related problem. In my project I have two separate maven projects. Every one of them is consumer and producer (separate topics). My contracts are placed in other repository.

So... There is scenario which I am currently working at:
We have 2 modules - module A and B. Module A sends messages to Kafka topics t1 and t2 on topics T1 and T2 and receives messages t3 and t4 from topic T3 and T4. Module B receives from T1 and T2 and sends to T3 and T4.

All consumer tests pass in every module. But producer tests end up with error mentioned in topic.

I suspect that this is caused by error in stub creation. So not proper listeners are set.

I tried different kafka configuration, but I believe it is not the case. I also checked spring cloud contracts configuration, but everything seems working fine. Proper jars with stubs are generated. Unfortunately, Google is not much of a help in this matter.

If you need any information in order to help me, feel free to ask.
I am working on it several days now, so I am desperate and really need your help.

EDIT: Added stack trace and relevant code snippets

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No consumer set up for topic [testSyncTopic]

at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.kafka.Receiver.receive(KafkaStubMessages.java:110)
at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.kafka.KafkaStubMessages.receive(KafkaStubMessages.java:80)
at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.kafka.KafkaStubMessages.receive(KafkaStubMessages.java:42)
at com.comarch.fsm.dispatcher.rest.ContractBaseTest.setup(ContractBaseTest.groovy:56)
```

Base test class configuration:

```
@SpringBootTest
@EmbeddedKafka(bootstrapServersProperty = "spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", brokerProperties = ["log.dir=target/embedded-kafka"])
@AutoConfigureStubRunner
abstract class BaseTestConfig extends Specification {
}
```

My contract definition:

```
Pattern customDateTime() {
    Pattern.compile('([0-9]{4})-(1[0-2]|0[1-9])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9])T(2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])Z')
}

Contract.make {
    label("sync")
    input {
        triggeredBy("sync()")
    }
    outputMessage {
        sentTo("testSyncTopic")
        body(
                syncStart: $(customDateTime())
        )
    }
}
```

ContractBaseTest class:

```
abstract class ContractBaseTest extends BaseTestConfig {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaService kafkaService;

    def synchronizeData() {
        kafkaService.sendKafkaMessage("testSyncTopic", null, new SyncDto(new Date()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Describing the problem won't let anyone help you solve it. Please add all the relevant configuration / code snippet / exception trace...

Comment: @tmarwen I updated the question. I believe now there is enough information to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does your base test class have `@AutoConfigureStubRunner` it should have `@AutoConfigureMessageVerifier`? It seems you're mixing the consumer and the producer sides.

Please check the example of a producer with Kafka over here: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/master/producer_kafka . For readibility reasons I'll copy paste it here.

**THE PRODUCER**

The base class: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/master/producer_kafka/src/test/java/com/example/BaseClass.java

```
package com.example;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
// remove::start[]
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.boot.AutoConfigureMessageVerifier;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafka;
// remove::end[]
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
// remove::start[]
@AutoConfigureMessageVerifier
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, topics = {"topic1"})
// remove::end[]
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public abstract class BaseClass {

    @Autowired
    Controller controller;

    public void trigger() {
        this.controller.sendFoo("example");
    }
}
```

Here you can find the controller

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.common.Foo1;

/**
 * @author Gary Russell
 * @since 2.2.1
 */
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> template;

    @PostMapping(path = "/send/foo/{what}")
    public void sendFoo(@PathVariable String what) {
        this.template.send("topic1", new Foo1(what));
    }

}
```

here you can see the production configuration (`application.yml`)

```
spring:
  kafka:
    producer:
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.contract: debug
```

and here you can see the test configuration (`application-test.yml`)

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: ${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}
    consumer:
      properties:
        "key.serializer": "org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer"
        "key.deserializer": "org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer"
      group-id: groupId
```

and the contract (https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/master/producer_kafka/src/test/resources/contracts/shouldSendFoo.groovy)

```
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

Contract.make {
    label("trigger")
    input {
        triggeredBy("trigger()")
    }
    outputMessage {
        sentTo("topic1")
        body([
                foo: "example"
        ])
    }
}
```

**THE CONSUMER**

Now time for the consumer (https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tree/master/consumer_kafka)

```
package com.example;

import org.assertj.core.api.BDDAssertions;
import org.awaitility.Awaitility;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
// remove::start[]
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.StubTrigger;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.AutoConfigureStubRunner;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.StubRunnerProperties;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafka;
// remove::end[]
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
// remove::start[]
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(ids = "com.example:beer-api-producer-kafka", stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.LOCAL)
@EmbeddedKafka(topics = "topic1")
// remove::end[]
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class ApplicationTests {

    // remove::start[]
    @Autowired
    StubTrigger trigger;
    @Autowired
    Application application;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        this.trigger.trigger("trigger");

        Awaitility.await().untilAsserted(() -> {
            BDDAssertions.then(this.application.storedFoo).isNotNull();
            BDDAssertions.then(this.application.storedFoo.getFoo()).contains("example");
        });
    }
    // remove::end[]

}
```